# "Method foo() needlessly boxes a boolean constant" Sonar warning

Tags: java, sonarqube

We have a bunch of these messages being reported in our Java code by SonarQube's analyzers.

> Method `foo(String, String)` needlessly boxes a boolean constant

In many cases it is returning `true` for `Boolean` return type method.

I am wonder to what extent is this a (performance?) problem with Oracle Java 8 in 2017? Does it really end up creating new `Boolean` instance or does it optimize into `Boolean.TRUE` auto-magically?

**UPDATE**

The Sonar rule key is `fb-contrib:NAB_NEEDLESS_BOOLEAN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION`.

Comment: Can you specify the rule key of the rule raising the issues?

Comment: @Michael-SonarSourceTeam: Updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasoning behind this issue is that you are invoking a method for no good reason. How can we verify this : 
Let's take this (complicated ;)) code

```
  Boolean foo(String s) {
   return true;
  }
```

What can be done is decompile this. This gives us the following bytecode instruction (simplified a bit for brevity)

```
ICONST_1
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Boolean.valueOf (Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
ARETURN
```

As you can see there is a method invocation to create a `Boolean` from constant 1.

If we now change the code to something like:

```
  Boolean foo(String s) {
   return Boolean.TRUE;
  }
```

bytecode generated is :

```
GETSTATIC java/lang/Boolean.TRUE : Ljava/lang/Boolean;
ARETURN
```

Which is getting a static constant and returning it which should be more efficient.

Comment: "which should be more efficient" the JIT will do a fine job of making them identical.

Comment: I fully agree. That's why I used conditional here, this is the reasoning of the check and it is most probably optimized by the VM.

Comment: It won't be more efficient.  The JVM inlines this tiny static method and further, can trivially convert the compiled assembly to be the same.